# SQL column renamed generating error in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

**Context:**

I have a dates table that I pulled in just by checking its box in the add data wizard which generated this

```
= Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="vw_ReportDates"]}[Data]
```

then I renamed the column ReportDayNo to DayOfReportMonth and I now get to see DayOfReportMonth in the data model but I get an error saying ReportDayNo doesn't exist. I'm not sure what to do here, the code doesn't explicitly call out for ReportDayNo so I'm not sure where to correct this.

**Question:**

how do I tell Power Query this column no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

You have following options (for Table.RenameColumns step):

1. Delete this step completely (if ReportDayNo was only column you renamed);
2. Delete the chunk `{"ReportDayNo", "DayOfReportMonth"}` from your step (if there are other columns you renamed);
3. Add 3rd argument `MissingField.Ignore` to your Table.RenameColumns function. More info:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powerquery-m/table-renamecolumns

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, I don't currently have a Table.RenameColumns step, the column was renamed in the SQL view [dbo].[vw_ReportDates], do I need to add a Table.RenameColumns step? if so, how / where would I do that?

Comment: Well, I guess I misunderstood you. I thought, you've renamed column in Power BI initially, then you've performed same operation in SQL view. Now I guess, the cause is Table.TransformColumnTypes step (see Applied steps). It appears automatically by default. So you should replace ReportDayNo for DayOfReportMonth in this step or delete this step completely, if data types are ok.